# How to do a minimal non-server install of Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

I really want to switch to Ubuntu 19.04 for my main workstation, however I want a very minimal installation with i3 and lightdm.
I don't want to manually figure out which packages to purge on the regular Ubuntu installation, so I just tested the beta of the 19.04 server and selected absolutely no features in the installer.
Even so it still holds quite a few server features, such as for instance cloud-init.
So using the server image isn't really an option either.

How can I install a strictly minimal Ubuntu with no window manager, zero Gnome/KDE/XFCE/etc. based applications and really just the bare essentials to boot into a terminal?
I'll add the necessary packages myself from there.

Note: I've looked through the similar questions, but they all suggest going the server route, which as mentioned really isn't all that feasible IMO as it adds too many server features.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at using the mini.iso 
There is some info on that ISO over at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD.
With that being said, the ISO does not support UEFI out of the box and requires you to add support if you need or want that.
They also document a portion of this on that same page (direct link - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#mini_system_in_UEFI_mode).

I have been working on an Ansible script to build up an I3 install as well. If you get stuck on the UEFI portion, let me know. I did script it. However, I am not at my computer to grab that info.

Comment: I'll give the mini.iso a spin without UEFI at first, I'm not entirely sure it allows a minimal install. As I read it it's just for doing a network installation rather than downloading the entire image upfront (but I could be wrong ofc.)

Comment: @Steffen - no you are correct, it is a network install, but if you do not select any of the optional packages - it is about as minimal as you can get (from my understanding).